# How to separately edit two items imported from the same JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this in my `index.html`

```
<div class="card" id="item1">
            <img src="images/toy1.jpg" class="thumbnail" id="toy1">
            <div class="card__content">
              <p class="card__title">Nerf Guns</p>
              <p class="card__description">$49.99</p>
            </div>
          </div>
```

and I also have the following javascript code there.

```
<script>
      function showNotification(title, price) {
          var notificationBox = document.getElementById('notificationBox');
          notificationBox.style.display = 'block';
          setTimeout(function () {
              notificationBox.style.display = 'none';
          }, 2000);
  
         
          localStorage.setItem(title, 'true');
          
      }
  
      
      for (let i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
          let item = document.getElementById('item' + i);
          let title = item.querySelector('.card__title').innerText;
          let price = item.querySelector('.card__description').innerText;
  
          item.addEventListener('click', function () {
              showNotification(title + ' ' + price);
          });
      }
  </script>
```

The javascript adds the item's `card__title` and `card__description` to the local storage and then here is part of the javascript for my `cart.html`

```
<ul id="cartItemsList"></ul>

    <script>
        
        function removeItem(itemId) {
            localStorage.removeItem(itemId);
            displayCartItems();
        }

        
        function displayCartItems() {
            var cartItemsList = document.getElementById('cartItemsList');
            cartItemsList.innerHTML = ''; 

            for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
                var itemId = localStorage.key(i);
                var itemValue = localStorage.getItem(itemId);

                if (itemValue === 'true') {
                    var listItem = document.createElement('li');
                    listItem.textContent = itemId;

                    var removeButton = document.createElement('button');
                    removeButton.textContent = 'Remove';

                    removeButton.addEventListener('click', (function(id) {
                        return function() {
                            removeItem(id);
                        };
                    })(itemId));

                    listItem.appendChild(removeButton);
                    cartItemsList.appendChild(listItem);
                }
            }
        }

        window.onload = displayCartItems;
    </script>
```

[image: add item]

[image: add item]

[image: cart]

When I click on the items in the `index.html` they are added to the local storage and then appear in the cart. I want to edit the styling and position of the name and price separately on the `cart.html` page so I can place them wherever I want on the page. At first, I tried

```
item.addEventListener('click', function () {
              showNotification(title);
              showNotification(price);
```

but that added the name and the price as two different products in the cart and now it's `showNotification(title + ' ' + price);` where I just added a space between them, but now they are not separate components.
I am sorry if the answer is something obvious, but I'm relatively new to this and still learning, so I appreciate your patience and assistance!

Comment: `showNotification` takes two arguments, title and price. The code only provides one. Putting code to format the notification in `showNotification` and calling it with two arguments may be a way to solve the design problem.

Comment: You could also create two separate components in the `showNotification` function, append them to the same parent and append this parent to your list. This way you will be using both the title and the price, since one of the two is unutilized.